# mssql/php - Looping through resultset and performing new query efficiently - In-Memory Tables?

Tags: php, sql-server, in-memory

I am fairly new to MSSQL and have never used In-Memory Tables and am not 100% sure if this is what I need.

I have a result set from a query (which cannot be amended) and I loop through and display each row of data.  For one field of the result set I need to perform a query to get the relevant display data for that field.  The issue is I may have to potentially call this query 1000's  of times within the loop depending on how many rows there are in the result set.

Can anyone advise on ways to do this efficiently?  I have heard of In Memory tables and am wondering if this is what I need?  If so where do I start?  Or do I simply store in an array or something?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Test_Memory_Table Table
(
/* Fields needed for lookup; use same datatypes as schema */ 
IndexOrPkFieldName Numeric(19,0),
Field1 varchar(255),
Field2 date
)

Insert into @Test_Memory_Table Select t2.Field1 as field1, t1.field2 as Field2, CONVERT(char(10),t3.Field3, 101) as Field3 
                 From   Table1 t1 
                 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.pkId = t2.pkId and isnull(t2.IS_ACTIVE,0) = 1  and ISNULL(t2.TYPE, 0) > 0 
                 INNER JOIN Table3 t3 on t2.pkId = t3.pkId

select * from @Test_Memory_Table
```

Just test the query in SSMS and look at the plan to see how long it takes to return the memory table query versus querying the table directly.  remember that ssms can be faster than production because of hints defaulted in ssms (e.g. arithabort), but may not be set that way when querying through .net client.  If your tables are small I would expect the difference to be marginal.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, I am a little confused by this.  Do I replace your select query with my own?

Comment: I think the bottom line is, I don't really understand where to use table variables / temporary tables or how this is any better than doing what I am already doing and calling a query directly within the result set.  I am trying to find scenarios but cannot find anythign and am therefore unsure if this is something I should be using and if so how do I implement this?